# Speed up Oracle 12c text query for a big table

Tags: oracle12c

I have a table with 4 million records. This query runs fast

```
SELECT Id
  FROM Table1
  WHERE contains(Text,'great OR good') >0 
  OFFSET 10 ROWS   FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              |     3 |   225 |  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |              |     3 |   225 |  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |              | 35926 |    64M|  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Table1       | 35926 |    64M|  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     DOMAIN INDEX              | IDX_ADS_TEXT |       |       |  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this query

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE contains(Text,'great OR good') >0 
ORDER BY SomeDateColumn
OFFSET 10 ROWS   FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              | 35926 |  2947K|       | 20265   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |              | 35926 |  2947K|       | 20265   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK     |              | 35926 |    64M|    70M| 20265   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Table1       | 35926 |    64M|       |  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     DOMAIN INDEX              | IDX_ADS_TEXT |       |       |       |  6035   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

runs super slow. What can I do and what is the reason? I have index on `SomeDateColumn`

Comment: How many rows does your query return? An index on SomeDateColumn is not going to help in this instance. Can you post the execution plans of the two queries, and you'll see why.

Comment: added execution plans, thanks

Comment: @BobC what about  `Ascending and Descending Indexes` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm?

Comment: What about them? You are not accessing the table via the index that gives the order of the output.

Comment: so is there a better solution than pre-sorted materialized views? if `craiglist` would be running on Oracle, what would be a solution for allowing fast search by filters and order by date/price. Because that's what I need basically https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/aap?sort=rel&availabilityMode=0&max_price=10000&min_price=100&query=large

Comment: When I search craigslist, I usually have some strong filters; queries will return maybe 100s or 1000s of records. So my original question; how many rows does your query return?

Comment: yeah I see. My query returns millions, even after applying some initial filters. I guess it is more `ebay` type, when I key in something common like `samsung` and there are millions of matches and 5 types of sorting

Comment: What machine are you running on; how many CPU's (cores); how much IO Bandwidth?

Comment: OVH dedicated server Intel Xeon E5-1650v3 6c 64GB, 500 Mbps (but bandwidth is not super important I guess becuase we show only 4 results at a time and more when scrolling). We can upgrade to - 20c/256GB or more I guess. Currently we have pre-sorted materialized views system in place but it's a pain, refreshing is slow

Comment: Just ignore all that @BobC is saying. He has no idea what he is talking about, I will be posting a solution here

Answer (score 2):

It is doubtful that you can improve performance much.

Why the difference? Imagine: I have a basket with 4 million tennis balls in it. They are of different colors, and each has a date written on it.

Problem 1: pick balls from the basket; ignore the first 10 that are either blue or green, and then keep (return) the next three.

Problem 2: find ALL the blue and green balls in the basket. Arrange them in the order of the dates written on them. THEN ignore the first 10 (in order of date) and return the next three.

In problem 1, it is possible that only 50,000 balls (or even far fewer) were even looked at until 13 of them were either blue or green.

In problem 2 you must look at all 4 million balls, and keep only the blue and green ones. Then you must spend extra time ordering them.

I hope you can see why it is possible that problem 1 can be solved very quickly, but problem 2 may take a really long time.

Comment: Nicely explained. It's all in the execution plan :)

Comment: what can I do? I made a materialized view with the sorting clause and it works quick. But that will mean mat.view for every sorting

Comment: @Toolkit I'm sorry you feel that way about Oracle. Apart from your materialized view option, is there a way to filter the query down so that you do not have to sort such a large results set, only to get rows 10-13?

Comment: @BobC, no the user needs to be able to search among 4 million records and sort and paginate result by different fields. I guess several materialized views is the only option

Comment: @Toolkit. If you have sufficient resources, CPU and IO bandwidth, then you can apply the big hammer and throw some parallelism at the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need different MV's for different sorting orders. By far the performance drag is finding ALL the records that satisfy the expensive `WHERE` condition. Do you have queries with different phrases to search for? THAT would be the big problem. If you have different sorting criteria for the same `WHERE` condition, you only need one MV.

Comment: just an update that we went down pre-ordered MV road and so far so good. We explored indexing and ordering on the fly and it wasn't good

Comment: @mathguy have you considered `Ascending and Descending Indexes` when answering?https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm

Comment: mathguy and @BobC from Oracle Corporation, you have no clue how to use idexes. amazing! Start from the basics will you

Comment: @Toolkit - what can we do, we can’t all be geniuses like you. Question is, if you know so much, how come you ask for help on free websites?

Comment: Toolkit, I think it's pretty inappropriate of you to start questioning my knowledge and ability, and similarly for @mathguy. This is a resource where we share our knowledge and time for free. I suggest you keep your comments to those based on numerical facts.